# Center content in card

Tags: vmware-clarity

I wonder how to center vertically and horizontally the content of a card text (or card block).

[image]

Here's the code I'am using

```
<div class="clr-row">
  <div class="clr-col-2">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">This month credits used</div>
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="card-text" *ngIf="credits.length > 0">
          <h1>{{creditsCurrent | number : '1.2-2'}}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the "70.10" string to be aligned vertically and horizontally

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `h1` here for styling purposes is not advised as you'll get issues with accessibility understanding the DOM structure of the page.

You'll want to put the text straight into the `div.card-text` element. Then create a set of styles that reflects the styling you want for the text, and in this case I've setup a new class so I can easily reuse this elsewhere.

```html
<div class="clr-row">
  <div class="clr-col-2">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">This month credits used</div>
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="card-text numeric-card-text" *ngIf="credits.length > 0">
          {{creditsCurrent | number : '1.2-2'}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.numeric-card-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the <h1> is a bad idea. Your CSS works : the text is centered horizontally. Do you know how to center it vertically. Thank you

Comment: Use CSS to manage the layout, here is another description https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css